# setTextAppearance deprecated android how to use?

Tags: android

```
 layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relate);
                TextView tv = new TextView(DetailActivity.this);
                layout.addView(tv);
                tv.setTextAppearance(DetailActivity.this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                tv.setText("Hello Man");
```

Here is my code how to use setTextAppearance for API > 23

Help Appreciated

Comment: what is your question? what is not working?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `TextViewCompat` from support library:

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(tv, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

Comment: This also works on other widgets that extends TextView like Chip, Checkbox, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                titleTextView.setTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_MaterialComponents_Headline6);
            } else {
                titleTextView.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.TextAppearance_MaterialComponents_Headline6);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For API > 23, do :

```
tv.setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Medium);
```

Comment: If you support API < 23 (as most devs do at the moment) the code gets messy as you'll have put loads of `if (SDK >= 23)` - best to use    `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(view, resId)`

Answer (score 0):

it means you don't need to put the context arg there you can simply put the style id.  it gets context automatically now

Comment: Only from API >=23 - if you support below this SDK you'll have litter your code with `if (SDK >= 23)` - best to use `TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(view, resId)`